# How to push code back to git in a Jenkins Pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I check out code from git like this

```
stage('Checkout code') {
   checkout scm
}
```

and modify the repository in the subsequent phase? Things like a git tag or a version commit.

Answer (score 3):

Best I could come up with.

```
stage('Stage Checkout') {
        checkout([
            $class                           : 'GitSCM',
            branches                         : scm.branches,
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
            extensions                       : [] + [
                $class     : 'LocalBranch'
            ],
            userRemoteConfigs                : scm.userRemoteConfigs,
        ])
    }

    //do git stuff

    stage('Push Version Back to Git') {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'jenkins', usernameVariable: 'GIT_AUTHOR_NAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
            sh 'echo ${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME} pushing '
            sh 'git config --global user.email "user@test.com"'
            sh 'git config --global user.name "Jenkins"'
            sh 'git config --global push.default simple'
            sh('git push https://${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@github.com/a/a.git')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Having it as follows made it working to me. And another thing to remember is, if your password or username contains any **special characters**, make sure that they have been saved in the credentials with the encoded characters. Other it's never gonna work.

This happened to me too and I wasted hours... Crazzzy...

```
pipeline {

    // ..

    stages {
        stage('Clone') {
            steps {
                sh "git config --global user.email 'root@my-domain.com'"
                sh "git config --global user.name 'My Name'"
                sh 'git config --global push.default simple'

                withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '123123ghghjg13123', usernameVariable: 'GIT_AUTHOR_NAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
                    sh('git clone https://${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@my-repo.git')
                }

            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // ...
            }
        }
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '123123ghghjg13123', usernameVariable: 'GIT_AUTHOR_NAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
                    sh('git push https://${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@my-repo.git  --tags -f --no-verify')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```